# Firestore: is there a simple way to attach extra data to users?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I use the recommended way to create a user with `Firestore` in my project, through the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
  (user) => {
    this.$store.commit('setUserId', user.user.uid);
  },
  (error) => {
    alert('Oops. ' + error.message)
  }
);
```

However I'd like to attach extra data to each user, namely, an object containing all projects he/she has worked on.

Does `Firestore` allow something like this (if so how?), or do I have to handle this manually by creating my own `userData` collection for example with a `userId` field along with the extra `projects` field?

Comment: Sure, you Firestore is fairly flexible in what you can store.  What is the problem you're running into writing extra data per user?  What have you tried?

Comment: I guess my problem is users aren't stored in a collection (to which I could add my own fields) but in a built-in container in which I cannot do that (or at least I have no idea how). I could create a collection and tie it in my code to the built-in user container (through something akin to a userId foreign key) but before taking than pain I want to make sure there's not something more elegant and easy than that.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have taken in the past has been to pair a document in a dedicated 'users' collection, with the ID of the Firebase User UID.

```js
db.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set(...)
```

Then within the authentication logic I check for any flags used to note the status of the user account; e.g. you may wish to perform onboarding, etc.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    const userRecordRef = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid)
    userRecordRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        if (doc.data().onboardingStatus === 'new_user') {
          root.$router.push('/onboarding')
        }
        ...
    })
    .catch(...)
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Firestore Security Rules should be used to ensure user documents are in the correct state whenever updated, since this is client side code.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, however my question was whether there is some simpler, built-in alternative to that solution you've put forward.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old but i would like to post my answer ass well am using react-saga for this...

first of all make a function that gets the  data you would like:

```
    export const handleNewData = (testdata) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .set(testdata)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const usersArray = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            ...doc.data(),
            documentID: doc.id,
          };
        });
        resolve(usersArray);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

after that make a new function that handles your data in to your database (in this function put your old data also) code example:

```
        export function* addData({
  payload: {
    newData1,
    newData2,
    newData3,
    birthDay,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    nickName,
    email,
  },
}) {
  try {
    yield handleNewData({
      newData1,
      newData2,
      newData3,
      birthDay,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      nickName,
      email,
      userUID: auth.currentUser.uid,
    });
  } catch (err) {}
}

export function* onAddTestData() {
  yield takeLatest(userTypes.ADD_NEW_DATA_START, addData);
}
```

LAST STEP AND THE MOST IMPORTANT
dont forget to fetch your Data in your new Form and Dispatch your values again!

```
      const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      addDataStart({
        newData1,
        newData2,
        newData3,
        birthDay: userDetails.birthDay,
        firstName: userDetails.firstName,
        lastName: userDetails.lastName,
        nickName: userDetails.nickName,
        email: userDetails.email,
      })
    );
  };
```